# IllegalLocationConstraintException while connecting to s3 by amazon api

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to connect s3 with api gateway. There is no available bucket region for my current location, so I use the nearest one for the bucket. When I'm trying to connect with API, it throws IllegalLocationConstraintException, because, I'm connecting from another region...
All the solution on the internet is about adding region to the URL, or some parameters like --region, but where should I add them in API gateway?! I can't see any fields, to add something like this. What should I do?

Comment: you're connecting S3 with API Gateway to achieve what? S3 is object store and API Gateway is for "APIs". More details on the architecture might help

Comment: I want to connect NoCode app constructor Adalo to S3 storage, to store there files and images. I can't write there any code, just make simple HTTP calls with headers queries and json body. So, i thought that I can create API to call it from Adalo, passing the file URL and uploading files to the S3 storage.